# Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, same-origin-policy

I am working on a website, let say the website name is "https://website" **(which is built on wordpress)** in which I am getting the following error on console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://website" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

    at contents (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,utils,underscore,wp-util,backbone,&load%5B%5D=moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2:26921)

    at Function.map (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,utils,underscore,wp-util,backbone,&load%5B%5D=moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2:3613)

    at a.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,utils,underscore,wp-util,backbone,&load%5B%5D=moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2:27001)

    at b (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=postbox,thickbox,hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,wp-a11y,updates,plugin-install,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,shortcode,wp-ba&load%5B%5D=ckbone,media-models,wp-plupload,wp-mediaelement,wp-api-request,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgareaselect,&load%5B%5D=image-edit&ver=4.9.8:347:103)

    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=postbox,thickbox,hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,wp-a11y,updates,plugin-install,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,shortcode,wp-ba&load%5B%5D=ckbone,media-models,wp-plupload,wp-mediaelement,wp-api-request,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgareaselect,&load%5B%5D=image-edit&ver=4.9.8:347:1306)

    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,utils,underscore,wp-util,backbone,&load%5B%5D=moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:3:12444)

    at HTMLBodyElement.r.handle (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,utils,underscore,wp-util,backbone,&load%5B%5D=moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:3:9173)

    at Object.trigger (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,utils,underscore,wp-util,backbone,&load%5B%5D=moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:3:11573)

    at Object.a.event.trigger (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,utils,underscore,wp-util,backbone,&load%5B%5D=moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:9:8275)

    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,utils,underscore,wp-util,backbone,&load%5B%5D=moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:3:18991)
```

**The above error** is generated by clicking `View Details` section of wordpress plugins (as shown below):

[image]

This error seems to exist in **every single wordpress plugins** but it works when I open in a new tab but it doesn't work when I open in the same window.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering which file I need to modify in wordpress in order to solve this error. This error seems to exist in every wordpress plugins. **As mentioned, it works in a new tab but fails to work in the same page**.

I have a feeling I have to make some changes in the following file by seeing the error above (**load-scripts.php, as the error is generated in that file**) but not sure what line I need to add in order to make it work.

**https://website/wp-admin/load-scripts.php**

Comment: It sounds like the entire Wordpress site is loaded within an iframe. Please take a look at the pages source code and check if it is. The link is there for trying to load inside the iframe which could explain why it works when you open in a new window.

Comment: @Sarcoma Where I need to look for the page source code ? or Which file I need to check for the page source code ?

Comment: Just view source in the browser and see where the iframe is. It should tell you what it is requesting in its `src` attribute, that might tell you why it's requesting resources outside of your domain. It looks like @Blackbam knows why the iframe exists. If you can see a domain in the iframe src it might give you a clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: @Sarcoma I am sending you the [link](https://test.caubo.ca/) of the website on which I am working on and which is causing this bug. When I globally search iframe here, I can see `iframe is commented` from `line#106 to line#108` and iframe is used in css as well. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @Sarcoma and Iframe is also used in css at `line#341`

Comment: @Sarcoma Are you around ?

Comment: When you say `https://website` what is the actual domain that is blocked? is it identical to the link you sent or is there a difference? I'd expect them to be different to throw that error if you see what I mean.

Comment: Its same. I didn't mention in the question.

Comment: Is it asking for password ? Let me know.

Comment: Here is the [website](https://test.caubo.ca/) which I am working on but I don't think so its public.

Comment: @Sarcoma Are you around ?

Comment: Yes, it is asking for a password.

Comment: You have indicated they are the same, but the error suggests that they are not. Even if the subdomain is different it will throw this error I believe. I was thinking as you are on a `https://test.website.com` that it could be looking for `https://website.com` or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184593/discussion-between-john-and-sarcoma).

Answer (score 3):

Something bad has happend to your WordPress admin interface.

The first thing to notice is that the error you have described is a well known problem as you may have already noticed: [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Look at the first answer there:

> You can't access an  with different origin using JavaScript,
>   it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it. For the
>   same-origin policy browsers block scripts trying to access a frame
>   with a different origin.
>
> **Protocol, hostname and port must be the same** of your domain, if you
>   want to access a frame.

The second thing to notice is what the **"View details"** button in the WordPress admin interface does: It opens a ThickBox containing and iframe which is showing remote contents quite often within an IFrame. How this works is ecactly described here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/ThickBox

`load-scripts.php` is an important WordPress core file loaded in the admin which is used to load JavaScript files without having to embed each of them. Those JavaScript files are usually added to your WordPress admin with the `admin_enqueue_scripts()` function (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).

As your problem is quite uncommon and the "View details" button for Plugins works almost everytime there are only two possibilities:

**1. The "View Details" IFrame is usually loaded from the same location where your WordPress is - therefore you might have a problem such that the browser wants to load it from a different host**

This happens if you have some misconfiguration within your WordPress installation and Thickbox tries to get an IFrame from a host which the Browser thinks is another host. Configure WordPress correctly.

**2. You have a badly programmed plugin or theme which is injecting a script causing this problem**

Solution: Deactivate your theme and all your plugins one-by-one and see if the error still exists. This way you can find out the modification which causes the problem and maybe do a bug request to the plugin developers then.

*It is almost 100% sure that a single plugin, theme or misconfiguration is causing this problem.*

Comment: I will comment on your answer shortly.

Comment: Have you found it?

Comment: I will let you know by today.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I deactivated plugin `one-by-one` and then I clicked on the `view details` button for the deactivated plugin and the plugin which is not deactivated (for both of them). I found the bug still exists. Now, going to check themes.

Comment: There is two possibilities it could also be a problem with misconfiguration e.g. port in the URL.

Comment: How can we check that ? Which file I need to check in order to fix that ?

Comment: Can you check my comment in Sarcoma answer ? Maybe that can help.

Comment: Can you recommend some another solution in order to fix this problem ? This is the [link](http://test.caubo.ca/) of the website which I am working on. ( I didn't deactivate the theme because I was afraid that it might break the website )

Comment: As, I am using Custom theme so not sure if it breaks anything or not.

Comment: just deactivate and check with a default theme

Comment: I agree with @Blackbam. You can put your site in maintenance mode while testing or using a default theme. And also, yes, the issue could be caused by a code in the currently active theme on your site. If the issue persists after trying a default theme, backup your site (database and files) and try reinstalling WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, chances are your X-Frame-Options have either been set to deny by the server or a configuration was appended by another plugin, but the blocked frame issue may happen when your server has not been configured correctly or was configured with strict policies to prevent any sort of access to cross-origin frames. Since every plugin is affected when viewing the *Details* link, my answer coincides with what @Blackbam has explained regarding how it functions by bringing up a thickbox and uses an i-frame when explaining why they all don't seem to appear.

> I am wondering which file I need to modify in WordPress in order to
> solve this error. This error seems to exist in every wordpress
> plugins. As mentioned, it works in a new tab but fails to work in the
> same page.

So, for this particular case I don't believe it's necessarily a WordPress issue but a hosting server configuration and, depending on how much access you have to the server or wherever you're building the website, will determine what you can do to solve this error or whether or not you'll need to contact support to help you resolve it.

(*Since this answer is simply added for posterity, please excuse the present tense references used as I realize it's been 3 years since this was asked*)

## Solutions:

There are two options that may work for you, and will vary depending on your server and your user access.

### Solution 1: Adding permissions by modifying the .htaccess file

If your webhosting server is running on Apache or other supported web server, you can try adding the lines below to the [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
        Header always set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
        Header setifempty Referrer-Policy: same-origin
</ifModule>
```

For syntax, you can refer to to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options). But as another option, instead of setting `X-Frame-Options` to `"sameorigin"` you can also specify a particular domain so as to preserve the security feature if preferred, such as:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM website.com/*"
```

And replacing "website.com/*" with the domain you would like to permit, noting the space between `ALLOW-FROM` and the URL as further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805583/modify-headers-x-frame-options-in-htaccess). If you have other plugins installed that have modified your `.htaccess` file, be sure to place this entry above any Wordpress created entry as the `.htaccess` file is loaded in order and also note that it may not be supported in all browsers. Now, depending on the server security policies, if this doesn't work, then you'll have to  move on to the next solution.

### Solution 2: Modify your server configuration

Though I'm only including instructions for an Apache server from [here](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4415231266455-How-to-manage-X-Frame-Options-through-htaccess-for-your-website-) as reference, [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) includes configurations for Nginx, IIS, HAProxy, and Express as well. A full explanation can be found [here](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360052925073) if you have access to WHM and/or are running virtual servers and will require root access.

Log into the web server and look for the following file:

```
/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

# or you can also create a new file named 'include.conf' if it
# doesn't already exist
/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/{USERNAME}/{DOMAIN-NAME}/include.conf
```

If the file exists, you can either comment out the line if it's set to `DENY` to disable the restriction or add the line below to the newly created configuration file:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
</ifModule>
```

You'll then need to rebuild the configuration and restart the Apache server.

You can rebuild by running the command

```
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
```

Then restart with

```
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd
```

Without the `same-origin` setting, even though Wordpress is installed on the server, the jquery requests are being blocked as part of preventing any embedding of content from other sites as well. Read more about [Secure Headers from OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-project-secure-headers/)